# Listview Solution

Tags: android-studio, listview

I have created 3 edit text and a button i saved my all 3 edit text in a array list and showed it in a list :But Problem is that i want to

```
    1. first they are showing in vertically manner i want it in horizontal manner so that if i add more items it should be separated from the previous one .
    2. I want to add as many as list i want to add please provide me a hint either i should use for loop or what to get as many list as i want.        
    i was thinking to try for loop to get as many input to be added in listview.
```

Main code Oncreate MEthod for java

public class secondActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

```
EditText edit1,edit2,edit3;
Button button;
ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

    edit1=findViewById(R.id.name);
    edit2=findViewById(R.id.desigination);
    edit3=findViewById(R.id.post);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);


    button = findViewById(R.id.list_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<String> arryList = new ArrayList<String>();
            arryList.add(edit1.getText().toString());
            arryList.add(edit2.getText().toString());
            arryList.add(edit3.getText().toString());

            ArrayAdapter list = new ArrayAdapter(secondActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arryList);
            listView.setAdapter(list);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Toast.makeText(secondActivity.this, "hello "+ position, LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

}

No error comming just its hsowing my list in vertically and i want it in a same line and want to add as many as items in list at same time its not working only i am able to add it for one time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HorizontalListView or add orientation property to the ListView or RecyclerView instead of ArrayList,

Comment: okie sir thanku and what about how to add multiple time in list i am able to add it for onetime only !

Comment: used Recycler View  but got this problem if uh know can uh please help me out?

Comment: hlo sir please can uh help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this model of code to add item to listview any time :

```
public class MyListView extends ListActivity {

ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

int myCounter = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        listItems);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

//METHOD WHICH WILL HANDLE DYNAMIC INSERTION
public void addItemsToList(View v) {
    listItems.add("Clicked : " + MyCounter++);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:text="Add New Item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="addItemsToList"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

And also you can use HorizontalListView for add item horizontally to list